# Rails4 loading javascript files. (Asset Pipeline)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I am trying hard to have one of my javascript file load/work with a Rails4 app. 
The file is users.js.coffee . This is a catch all javascript file that I want loaded for all pages (not necessarily just for users controller)

If I try to load by localhost:3000/assets/users.js I can see the compiled JS file. However using cmd+o on chrome doesnt load the file and also the events are not fired so I know its not working(and loading)

Also tried running `bundle exec rake assets:clean assets:precompile`

I do not see any 500 or 400 or js errors in console. The simplest of users.js.coffee doesnt work as well

```
$(document).ready -> 
  alert('hello')
```

Some configs:

applcations.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require js-routes
//= require bootstrap-slider
//= require users
//= require_tree .
```

development.rb
  config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
  config.serve_static_assets = false

production.rb

```
  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = true
  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true
  config.assets.compile = false
  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.assets.debug=true
```

Also the users.js.coffee was working fine before I started playing around with getting bootstrap using bootstrap-sass etc (on an tangent,eventually ended up loading bootstrap from hosted CDNs in application.haml, not sure if it should interfere with how js files are loaded/works)

Any pointers to debug this is greatly appreciated. Already spent few hours and Asset Pipeline gets me everytime

Thanks
P.S:
I am deploying to heroku (however this fails in both dev and heroku so hopefully fixing in dev should be enough)

Answer (score 0):

Update `application.js` content by moving `//= require users` after all other libraries that your application's javascripts depend on but before the `require_tree .`:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require js-routes
//= require bootstrap-slider
//= require users
//= require_tree .
```

The order of requiring javascripts is important here.  If your file is `users.js.coffee` then you need `jQuery` for `coffeescript` so `jQuery` must be required before `users`.

Comment: Thanks @vee. Good catch. Totally missed that!. I think I changed the order while debugging. I restored it to the order you specified (editing in the questions)and still have the same issues. Any other things I can try ?

Comment: You're saying the file gets loaded successfully i.e. `200 OK`, it's the javascript in the file that doesn't execute correct?  Can you add your `users.js.coffee` to your question.

Comment: I do not see any 500 or 400 or console js errors. The simplest of js.coffee doesnt work as well $(document).ready ->
  alert('hello')
Also this js.coffee was working fine before I started playing around with getting bootstrap using bootstrap-sass etc (on an tangent ..eventually ended up loading bootstrap from hosted CDNs in application.haml)